# JPA ManyToMany updating record

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have `SpringBoot 2.1.3` App. I'm using `Spring Security` than I have two entity `User` and `Roles` similar to the follows:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private List<Roles> role;
}

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "ROLES")
public class Roles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role ruolo;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> users;
}
```

*Role* is a simple `enum` as follows:

```
public enum Role {
   ROLE_ADMIN,
   ROLE_USER;
}
```

Now let `SpringBoot` create empty `database` and suppose to add some default record:

[image]

For now consider that `Roles` table will contain at most 2 roles: *ROLE_ADMIN* and *ROLE_USER*. I manage to add new `User` with a `Roles`, I manage to delete `User` with respective `Role` (retrieving `User` -> getting `Roles` from `User` -> iterating `Roles` and for each one remove `User` -> deleting `User`:

```
User user = userService.getByPk(Id);

List<Roles> roles = user.getRoles(); // this list size should be always 1
for (Rolesr : roles) {
   r.getUsers().remove(user);
}

utenteService.deleteByPk(opeId);
```

will remove both `User` record and respective `Roles_User` record.

What I **can't do** is **CHANGE** user role.. As we can see in the image I have one `User` with *ROLE_ADMIN* `Roles`.

I want to change `Roles`, for this `User`, from *ROLE_ADMIN* to *ROLE_USER*! The function should modify `Roles_User` as follows:

```
roles_id  user_id
   2         1
```

I have tried everything but nothing works as expected. The best result obtained is to add two `Roles` (ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER) to the `User`:

```
roles_id  user_id
   2         1
   1         1
```

In that application ROLES are hierarchical and an `User` can have at max one `Role`. I have used `ManyToMany` relation because of is the default `SpringSecurity` DB implementation (I don't know if I can use `OneToMany` relation).

I'm going mad! Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code. You must remove the user from the users of the ADMIN role, and add it to the users of the USER role.

Answer (score 0):

Better, save the new list or [Check this link](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

```
User user = userService.getByPk(Id);
// Add your code to delete all association of an user
// Add below code to assign new role
List<Roles> roles = new ArrayList<>();
roles.add(Role.ROLE_USER);
user.setRoles(roles);

utenteService.updateByPk(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answer. @Atul Jain I have already tried your code but, without cascading, surely will not work.

Finally I manage to do it, here is the solution:

```
// getting my User and removing all his roles (max one)
User user = userRepository.findById(1L).get();
user.getRoles().clear();

// get ROLE_ADMIN Role
Roles adminRole = rolesRepository.findById(1L).get();

// get all users with ROLE_ADMIN role and removing my user
List<User> adminUsers = adminRole.getUsers();
adminUsers.remove(user); 

List<Roles> roles = new ArrayList<>();
// get ROLE_USER Role and adding my User
Roles role = rolesRepository.findById(2L).get();
role.getUsers().add(user);
roles.add(role);

user.setRoles(roles);

userRepository.save(user);
rolesRepository.save(adminRole);
rolesRepository.save(role);
```

I would like to remember that `JPA` interface doesn't have `update` method in his `Repository` and I can't instantiate a `Role` in this case because this `table` should be considered as `typological`, filled at Application startup and never (maybe rarely..:)) updated.

Therefore I have to fetch the `Role` I want to add.

Anyway can someone tell me why:

```
User user = userRepository.findById(1L).get();
List<User> adminUsers = adminRole.getUsers(); // adminUser CONTAIN user of previous line
adminUsers.remove(user) // user IS NOT REMOVED, if debugging I select whole line and Watch result is false
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have `Roles.users` set as the owning entity with `mappedBy='users'` in the `Users` table. Only changes made to the owning entity are persisted. Instead, try putting `mappedBy='roles'` in the `Roles` table.

Also, you should use `Set<Role> role` instead of `List` as a matter of course. Lists are ordered and JPA/Spring-Data will attempt to preserve ordering and which can be a performance overhead. Also, multiple XToMany relationships defined with `Lists` in JPA can be problematic.

While you may only want a single role for any user, Spring Security defines and handles `ManyToMany` relationships.

JPA has an update -- `persist`, which is both save or update. Also, changes made to an attached entity are persisted (updated) automatically.

Comment: Yes I know `JPA` update entities... he does it automatically with `save` method, if `Entity` has primary key setted `JPA` perform an `update` oherwise an `insert `operation. I just said to @Atul that method `updateByPk()` doesn't exist in `JpaRepository` interface.